# Mass Changing Mysql Values

Tags: mysql

well In my mysql database I have about 1.6 million entries that look something like this

`<image src=http://site1.com/img.jpg border=0>`

how can I change them to

`<image src=http://site2.com/img.jpg border=0>`

in the most efficient manner?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to migrate data? It is a exhaustive job... but what exactly do you wanna do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UPDATE yourTable SET someField = REPLACE(someField,'site1','site2')`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Why are you storiong HTML tags in the databse anyway? Just the addresses (relative, without a domain if the files are on your local server) should be enough.

Comment: it's a friends site and he's kinda dumb, i'm not sure why he's storing html tags in his db.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET StringColumn = REPLACE (StringColumn, 'site1.com', 'site2.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do an update query

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = '<image src=http://site2.com/img.jpg border=0>' 
WHERE columnName = '<image src=http://site1.com/img.jpg border=0>';
```